# Further explanation needed with combinatorics(hackerearth aryan-and-consulting-sessions)?

Tags: math, combinatorics

I am new to combinatorics problems and trying to understand how to solve this problem, I understand that nC2 is finding the numbers where order matters, but after that I have no idea how to proceed further in the math problem. Please explain further, no code needed.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/combinatorics/inclusion-exclusion/practice-problems/algorithm/aryan-and-consulting-sessions-0e0656ab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let students are graph vertices, possible pairs are edges. This graph is complete `K_n`, number of edges is `p = n*(n-1)/2`  (nC2 as you wrote)

We need to find number of [edge covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) for this graph.

I wanted to count numbers of edge covers containing from `(p+1)/2` to `p` edges, but seems values are too big and this is rather complex problem.

But we can find formula for counting overall quantity of edge covers for complete graph `K_n` [here in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006129)

```
 a(n) = Sum_{k=0..n} (-1)^(n-k)*binomial(n, k)*2^binomial(k, 2)
```

[You also need to calculate binomial coefficients modulo m](https://cp-algorithms.com/combinatorics/binomial-coefficients.html#toc-tgt-7)